# Test setup inheritance in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to create a test setup hierarchy in robot framework.

I have a sub-suite, that defines its own Test Setup - but this overrides the parent suite's Test Setup.

I want both Test setups to run - one after the other, first the Parent Test Setup (that is defined in **init**.txt) and after that the Test setup that is defined using the *** Settings *** section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of behavior at least with a bit of a hack way, by using [set global variable](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.1#Set%20Global%20Variable), [run keywords](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.1#Run%20Keywords) and an external resource file. This however requires you to define the test setup setting with a variable.

Example below:

Contents of __init__.txt:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource      Resource.txt
Suite setup   Set test setup variable
Test setup    Test setup keyword

*** Keywords ***
Set test setup variable
    Set global variable    ${test setup variable}    Test setup keyword
```

Contents of Resource.txt:

```
*** Keywords ***
Test setup keyword
    Log    Test setup from top level
```

Contents of Test_suite.txt:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource      Resource.txt
Test setup    Run keywords    ${test setup variable}    Test setup from test suite

*** Test cases ***
Test test setups
    Log    this should run two log keywords.

*** Keywords ***
Test setup from test suite
    Log    Test setup from test suite
```

I think this is the closest you can get.

Comment: Interesting stuff. I ended implementing it another way, also by using a Resource file and a stub function inside that resource file (that doesn't do anything) that the test suite could override. so in any case both test cases would run. But your solution is very good, maybe better.. I'll consider moving :)